# Defend Python socket from TCP SYN flood

Tags: python, sockets, server, flooding

I have an example of a server that gets commands and returns answers in python:

```
import socket
import time
import random

CommandDict = {"TIME" : time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y"),"NAME": "Ori","RANDOM": str(random.randint(0,10))}
server_socket = socket.socket()
server_socket.bind(('127.0.0.1',8820))
server_socket.listen(5)

while True:
    print "Waiting for commands"
    (client_socket, client_address) = server_socket.accept()
    client_data = client_socket.recv(1024)
    print "GOT COMMAND FROM " + client_address[0] + " : " + client_data
    try:
        client_socket.send(CommandDict[client_data])
    except Exception:
        client_socket.send("ERROR!")

    client_socket.close()

server_socket.close()
```

i tried a syn flood attack on it and it crashed.
i want to defend it from syn flood attacks, how could i do it?
i'm new to socket programming so i would be happy to get some advices ^_^

Comment: How exactly does it crash?

Comment: For one, you don't close client sockets when you are done with them.

Comment: before the attack i run the server in the cmd and it prints waiting for commands and after i run the attack it raises an exception:       
Waiting for commands
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Servers\CommandServer\Server.py", line 12, in <module>
    client_data = client_socket.recv(1024)
socket.error: [Errno 10054] ■■τΘßσ° ≈ΘΘφ ≡±Γ° ßδ⌠ΘΣ ≥∞-

Comment: As far as I know, SYN flood attacks have to be dealt with at the OS level.

Comment: @RussellBorogove is correct. A "syn flood" means the attacker sends a whole bunch of SYNs (possibly with spoofed source addresses) and never finishes the three-way handshake. The application never sees a connection, because no connections are actually established.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need a better server. As @Nikolai N Fetlissov pointed out, you are leaking file descriptors since you never closing the client connections.

Look at this example to see how to avoid this leak:

http://ilab.cs.byu.edu/python/socket/echoserver.html

In particular, note where the `client.close()` call is made and at what indentation level it is.

Next, you code only processes one command from the client. Have a look here:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578247-basic-threaded-python-tcp-server/

for a discussion on writing a threaded server which can handle multiple connections and multiple commands from each connection.

Finally, a user-space, socket-based program (more so, written in an interpreted language) is too slow to handle a real SYN flood in *just any way*. The standard approach is to use firewall software (and, after a certain margin, *hardware*) for that.